# Как перебрать массив объектов и суммировать значения?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть arrayOfSizez массив объектов следующего вида:

```js
[{height: 12312, offset: 21}, {height: 12312, offset: 21}, {height: 12312, offset: 21}.....]
```

Мне нужно суммировать все height и offset отдельно. Как это сделать?

Следующий вопрос:
цикл этого вида:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < arrayOfSizes.length; i++) {
          if (arrayOfSizes[i].offset < arrayOfSizes[i - 1].offset) {
            offset += arrayOfSizes[i].offset;
          }
        }
```

Нужно переписать через reducer, примерно такого вида:

```js
const offset = arrayOfSizes.reduce(
          (prev: any, val: any, i: any, arr: any) =>
            val.offset < arr[i].offset ? prev + val.offset : prev,
          0,
        );
```

Пока что то не так, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не совсем понятно в каком виде Вам его нужно вернуть. Например так собрать все суммы в один объект.

```
const result = arrayOfSizez.reduce((acc, el) => {
   acc.height += el.height;
   acc.offset += el.offset;
   return acc;
})

console.log(result);
```

Если нужно сохранить нетронутым исходный массив можно сделать так:

```
const result = arrayOfSizez.reduce((acc, el) => {
   acc.height = acc.height ? acc.height+el.height : el.height;
   acc.offset = acc.offset ? acc.offset+el.offset : el.offset;
   return acc;
}, {})
```

Или так:

```
const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayOfSizez)).reduce((acc, el) => {
   acc.height += el.height;
   acc.offset += el.offset;
   return acc;
})
```

Comment: Возможно, лучше задать начальное значение аккумулятора, иначе мы изменим также значение первого элемента исходного массива.

Comment: Добавил еще один вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. Кстати, предыдущий совет очень помог.

Comment: Мне не совсем понятна логика вашего цикла. Если offset текущего элемента меньше offset предидущего элемента, то в какую то неизвестную переменную offset нужно добавить offset текущего элемента. Опишите словами что вам нужно сделать. А лучше создайте отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Думаю данное решение будет оптимальным:

```js
const values = [
  { height: 12312, offset: 21 },
  { height: 12312, offset: 21 },
  { height: 12312, offset: 21 },
];

const getHeightAndOffsetSums = (items) => items
  .reduce((acc, { height, offset }) => {
    acc.heightSum += height;
    acc.offsetSum += offset;

    return acc;
  }, { heightSum: 0, offsetSum: 0 });

console.log(getHeightAndOffsetSums(values));
```

Comment: Добавил еще один вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. Кстати, предыдущий совет очень помог.